# How come Java accepts dynamic variable names in android studio 3.0.1?

Tags: java, android, variables, dynamic, naming

I was desperately trying to solve quiz11 of Arrays, Lists, Loops, and Custom classes (Udacity Android course for beginners). The problem with it was that I couldn't understand how to use loop to do the following for a total of 10 such TextViews.

```
TextView wordView1 = new TextView(this);
wordView1.setText(words.get(0));
rootView.addView(wordView1);

TextView wordView2 = new TextView(this);
wordView2.setText(words.get(0));
rootView.addView(wordView2);

TextView wordView3 = new TextView(this);
wordView3.setText(words.get(0));
rootView.addView(wordView3);
```

I couldn't figure out how I would change the names of TextView variables such as wordView1, wordView2, wordView3 in the loop. I thought giving them the same name would replace the previous TextView so the final output would be just nine on the top left corner of the screen (Which wasn't the case though). As I was desperate to solve it anyway, I tried this code even though I was certain it would not compile, let alone run successfully, because variable names can't have variables in them. But to my utmost surprise the following code worked:

```
for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++)
{
TextView wordViewi = new TextView(this); 
//Notice the i at the end of wordView?
wordViewi.setText(words.get(i));
rootView.addView(wordViewi);
}
```

Please let me know why this code works even though I added the counter variable i at the end of wordView variable name.

Answer (score 0):

There's no variable in your variable name.

Each iteration of your loop has a variable called `wordViewi`. The `i` in its name has no relation to your `i` loop variable.

Comment: LOL, I see that now, I was trying to find delete question when I found it myself moments ago. Thanks a lot anyway...